# JText string input, then display output to JList

Tags: java, swing

I am pretty new in Java programming, I have been trying to solve this simple program
it reads user input, then the ADD button will simply display the typed string on the `JList`.
The remove button will simply remove the desired item in the `JList`.

I am quite confused how to put the action listener thing in the code, or get text whatever
it is. I'd really appreciate if you can help me solve this simple GUI.

It reads user input in `JText` (String) and when I click the add button (maybe action performed?) the String will be basically populated in `JList`. and the Remove button will
simply remove the selected `String` in `JList`.

Comment: I have tried to retype some code from docs.oracle.com, but I cannot really understand what public, class, and lots of things there. I have read the tutorial, and I got what String, integer means, how to declare them, thats all pretty much. I made my GUI mockup in netbeans but I dont have enough reputation yet to post image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

Bind the code to the specific event, using the `addActionListener` method.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener({
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
            // Bind the method to the button.
       }
});
```

**Step 2**

Populate that method with the relevant code.

```
 String value = jTextBox.getText();
 // Grab the String value.
 jListModel.addElement(value);
 // And add it to the list model that informs the JList.
```

**Altogether**

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener({
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
              String value = jTextBox.getText();
              // Grab the String value.
              jListModel.addElement(value);
              // And add it to the list.
       }
});
```

**Useful Links**

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) is a very good tutorial from Oracle detailing how to manipulate lists a million and one different ways.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the explanation. I will retype the code in netbeans and give you feedback.

Comment: I have created a new project, and created the JPanel, the design is done, and back to the 'source' tab, I retype the code and put in private void addInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt), I dont get where to type the code if I start from JPanel 'source', this sounds really stupid :( sorry...

Comment: The name **must** be actionPerformed. It's because you're implementing a method from the `ActionEvent` interface.